# Splitting PATH environ variable into individual filepaths

Tags: c, path, environment-variables

I am trying to do simple shell as an exercise to myself. I am writing a function that should find an executable in the PATH, and return a pointer to a string, that contains the full path to executable. Here is what I have so far;

```
/*bunch of includes here*/

/*
 * Find executable in path, return NULL
 * if can't find.
 */
char *find_executable(char *command)
{
    const char *PATH = getenv("PATH");
    DIR *dp;
    /* get each pathname, and try to find executable in there. */
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{ /* nothing intersting here ...*/
}
```

I was wondering how should I separate each part of the path, and process these parts in a for loop.

Comment: Consider [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html) and [an example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: You really should get a good grasp on string parsing first if you're going to write a shell.

Comment: @jamesdlin The reason I am trying to write a shell is to have a goal while I practise. Otherwise, I get lost and bored. I am trying learn while trying to finish an application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment PATH Directories Iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295019/environment-path-directories-iteration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

say paths would be separated by ;
You can use strtok function to generate splitted token.
e.g.

`char *str = "/foo/a1/b1;/bar/a1/b1"`

Now you can use strtok function as

```
char delims[] = ";"  
char *result = NULL;  
result = strtok( str, delims );  
while( result != NULL ) {  
    dp = result;  
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );   
}
```

Comment: On linux paths are generally delimited by a colon, rather than a semicolon.